# fetching data from a usercontrol(.ascx file) and bind it in a tree format

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Here, I'm getting required data that is to be shown in a tree format which comes from a usercontrol i.e., UControl1.ascx. Now I need to show the data in tree format. As it is remote data I'm unable to bind it.
I got data into UControl1. Then binded to a placeholder and displayed it.Till this no issues. Now i need to show it in a treeview
The code I have used is shown below

```
UControl1 myControl = (UControl1)Page.LoadControl("~/Views/Controls/UControl1.ascx");
Views.Controls.UControl1 List1 = new UControl1();
myControl.Currentdata = Obj;
placeholder.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

Could anyone suggest me the way

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TreeView control`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx

Page Code :

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" Runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1"/>

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="Test.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Nota : TreeView control is binded to XmlDalaSource, this control load file Test.xml.

I ours case UserControl can contain public property that returns path

```
public class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
   public string PathXmlDataSource{get;set;}
}
```

So :

```
UserControl myControl = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/Views/Controls/UserControl.ascx");
YourTreeView.DataFile = myControl.PathXmlDataSource;
```

Comment: I have modified my post, once check it.